# how can i get one word and repeat 3 word

Tags: echo

Hello! Hello!
Your program will be given as input a single word, and it should print out that word three times, separating the words with spaces.

As a refresher, here are some ways to read a single word from standard input (when the first line of input contains a single word), in a few different languages:

## Python 3

#echo

help me to write this code

Answer (score 0):

```
word = str(input("User Input-->"))
lst = word.split(' ')

print(f'{lst[0]} '*3)
```

Here the formatting will come in handy to solve your problem